# Parse server data layout

Tags: parse-platform

I am working on a fairly large project using Parse server as the back end. my question is about the best way to store the data most efficiently for future proofing my system.

my design has the following:

```
Object1{
    attribute a,
    attribute b,
    attribute c,
    counter a,
    counter b,
    counter c
}
```

Basically, counters a,b,and c all get incremented and decremented when other objects are created or destroyed.
The counters are what I use to provide statistics on my main page of my application.

As a highest level user I might want to query for my top performing objects, perhaps to return the documents that have  counter b > 50.
My question is, will I lose efficiency if I put the counters all together into a counter object? I am trying to maintain maximum efficiency. Is there any problem like doing like I said previously as diagrammed below?

```
Object1{
        attribute a,
        attribute b,
        attribute c,
        Counter{counter a, b, c}
    }
```

Comment: You asking about speed if you make it a Pointer to another class??

Comment: Yes.  Does it lower performance by having to look at the other class?

Comment: Nope. Its all good for many projects that i've been working with!